# Upload any size image into carousel

Tags: plugins, image, php, upload

I wanted to create a php which allow admin to upload their pictures in any resolution and image file type, but it has to display into a bootstrap carousel with fixed size. 
Does anyone has the similar script I can have a look?

It might needed to do the following;
Upload image into a specific location, convert image type into jpg, specific resolution, and be able to read by bootstrap carousel. My head is about to broke thinking of this script :(

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to create a custom plugin to do that.

You can easily create a [Matrix](https://craftcms.com/features/matrix) content field for your carousel. Create a new block called `slide`. From there you can create an `asset` field to upload the slide image.

You can render this into whatever markup you'd like (even bootstrap).

As for cropping an image and converting it into a jpg, check out [Aviary Image Editor](https://github.com/fruitstudios/AviaryImageEditor). It's a wysiwyg editor in the admin panel for doing exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @PizzaBoy Just so you are aware, you can crop images in Craft using [image transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms) if you don't need the level of control Aviary provides.

If you need to have more control on how your images are cropped, I personally use two plugins: [Imager](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) with [FocalPointField](https://github.com/aelvan/FocalPointField-Craft). You can define a point of focus for your images in the CP, and Imager will detect it and make sure to include the focal point when cropping.